# Issue with adding Float values In java

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I have two values

```
5042034.0 
1425837.2
```

while I am adding like below

```
float abc = (float) (5042034.0 + 1425837.2);
```

I am expecting a result of `6467871.2`

But I am getting `6467871.0`

How could I get the `6467871.2` with the help of float?

I tried with

```
 float c = (float) (1.1 + 2.2) ;
```

I got a result : 3.3

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I think you should read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Floating point numbers do not have infinite precision. Specifically the type `float` has about 6 or 7 digits of accuracy. Beyond that you'll get roundoff errors. The results you see are what you should expect when you use `float`.

Comment: Hi.. I go through the link. I am working with an old product in that product every code were there. they used float at every where. so while I am trying to change this point will effect entire program So is there any way to solve this by using float itself?

Comment: No. It is a fundamental property of how the `float` type works. There's no way to magically make it be something else than it is...

Comment: Ok.. thank you for your valuable information

Comment: It's not really a problem with the addition; the `float` type is simply unable to represent the number 6467871.2.  The closest values it can represent are 6467871.0 and 6467871.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `double` instead.

```
double abc = (double) (5042034.0 + 1425837.2);
```

Comment: This works as well. Why the downvote here? I've upvoted this answer.

Comment: @EkabaBisong maybe because of the original version of the answer?

Comment: @xenteros Okay. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

Floats are IEEE 754 32-bit numbers.

5042034.0 is over 2^22. This means, that it fills 23 bits of mantisa which is the maximum. It actually skips the trailing 0.
When you're trying to add it to 1425837.2 it adjusts both numbers:

```
 10011001110111101110010.00
+  101011100000110101101.0011001100110011001101....
 --------------------------
 11000101011000100011111.0
```

in binary system. It means that `.0` and `.2` are out of 22 bit and are skipped.

If you want your arithmetic to be better, use `double` or `BigDecimal` instead of `float`:

```
double result = 5042034.0d + 1425837.2d;
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(5042034.0d + 1425837.2d);
```

Comment: The IEEE 754 binary32 type has a precision of 24 bits, not 22 bits.

Comment: @MarkDickinson isn't it 23? :) Anyway, 0.2 is 001... in binary

Comment: It's 24. See Table 3.2 in IEEE 754-2008. (Or if you prefer a secondary source, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).) Only 23 bits are explicitly stored in the binary interchange format, but that doesn't change the fact that the format has a precision of 24 bits.

Answer (score 2):

To support @xenteros answer, use `BigDecimal`.

```
BigDecimal abc = BigDecimal.valueOf(5042034.0 + 1425837.2);
System.out.println(abc);
```

will result in `6467871.2`.

Better still, use `double` which is a primitive:

```
double abc = (double) (5042034.0 + 1425837.2);
System.out.println(abc);
```

**N.B:** Just thought to contribute this, I know the OP asked with the help of float.

Comment: If you want to use BigDecimal anyway, then initialize BigDecimals with strings and then add those.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses IEEE 754 standard which support 6-7 significant decimal digits. Your addition result cross the range limit so you are getting such result.[image]